# Satellite angular velocity at an angle

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, geometry

Suppose I am observing a satellite that is not at my zenith. I know the altitude(α) and azimuth(γ) of my telescope and I was able to get a relative angular velocity of the satellite.

**Based on this information, is there a way to find the angular velocity when I am underneath the path of the satellite?**

If needed, I know the longitude and latitude of my location as well as the RA and DEC of where the telescope is pointed at.

Comment: _is there a way to find the real angular velocity_ What do you mean by _real_? If you mean _absolute_ (you mentioned you have calculated the relative angular velocity) then no, because _all_ velocities are relative.

Comment: the angular velocity as viewed at a location directly below the path of the satellite

Comment: You mean relative to you on earth as the satellite moves into your zenith? So the first measurement was relative to what? These are points you need to include in your question.

Comment: say i am in florida and the satellite passes from California to New York, when I observe the satellite from Florida it will seem like the angular velocity will be greater since I am further away, what I want to find is the angular velocity when I am directly in new york

Comment: Please edit your original post with that specific question. Also, do you know we [astronomy.stackexchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com)? You may find this question is more suited to that site. Thanks.

Comment: edited thank you! i will go and look around there as well!

Comment: No problems, and good luck with it.